# Add space between commas if it is not a number

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently performing pre-processing in a corpus using Python that will be used to perform Natural Language Processing and then Classification. I'm not interested in using any library as NLTK. As I'm learning, I prefer doing it by myself this time.

Well the problem is that I have to add a space between commas in a sentence if the commas are not preceded or followed by a number:

```
Input: "My car costs $10,000."
Output: "My car costs $10,000."

Input: "Oh, I forgot my keys."
Output: "Oh , I forgot my keys."
```

What I have so far is:

```
re.sub(r"(,+)", r' \g<1> ', sentence)
```

the problem is that it does not take into account the "number constraint". I also tested:

```
re.sub(r"[^\d](,+)", r' \g<1> ', sentence)
```

It indeed ignores numbers, but when checking ordinary sentences (no numbers), it also matches the character before the comma and it gets replaced by the space as:

```
Input: "Oh, I forgot my keys."
Output: "O , I forgot my keys."
```

Comment: Oh regex `:')`.... Now for some mindless pseudo-parsing.

Comment: maybe just search for a ',' get the index and check if i+1 and i-1 are numbers. if not, replace ',' with ' ,'

Comment: What should happen to `The car costs $10,000,but ,oh, I forgot my keys.`? Should it become `The car costs $10,000 , but , oh , I forgot my keys.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r"(?<![\d])(,+)(?![\d])", r' \g<1> ', sentence)
```

This is using something called [lookahead and lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This works because values matched by lookahead or lookbehind are not part of the match, and so are not replaced by sub.

Answer (score 1):

Using negative lookahead and lookbehind:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(,)(?!=\d)')
>>> r.sub(r' \1', "My car costs $10,000.")
'My car costs $10,000.'
>>> r.sub(r' \1', "Oh, I forgot my keys.")
'Oh , I forgot my keys.'
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex you would be looking for is this,

```
(?=,)(?<!\d)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/iW0iZ4

It is a zero width match so you would just replce with a  (space) and that's it.